# How to go through a loop in vbs while repeating a specific command

Tags: loops, vbscript

So I want my VBScript to go through different command like:

```
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
```

While in between each of those commands it will have a `Wscript.Sleep 1000` command.

Doing:

```
Command 1
Wscript.Sleep 1000
Command 2
Wscript.Sleep 1000
Command 3
```

Seems extremely tedious. I was wondering if there was a way in I could LOOP this for simplification.

EDIT: Here's my script. I want to simplify putting the sleep between each command.

```
'DeathTech Macro WORD
'
'### PRESETS START ###
'
Set wshShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
'
'### PRESETS END ###
'
'### SYSTEM VARIABLES START (DO NOT EDIT) ###
'
sysvariableEndPopupTitle="Finished Running Macro"
sysvariableEndPopupString="The Macro has finished running!"
sysvariablePopupDuration=8
sysvariablePopupTitle="Notification"
sysvariablePopupString="Please switch to Microsoft Word quickly. The macro will start in 8 seconds. Do NOT press the OK button. You must not touch the keyboard/mouse when the macro is running!"
sysvariableHomeButton="%h"
sysvariableFontButton="FF"
sysvariableSizeButton="FS"
sysvariableBoldButton="1"
sysvariablePageLayoutButton="%p"
sysvariableMarginButton="M"
sysvariableMarginButton2="{DOWN}"
sysvariableInsertButton="%n"
sysvariableHeaderButton="H"
sysvariableHeaderButton2="{DOWN}"
sysvariablePageButton="NU"
sysvariablePageButton2="B"
sysvariablePageButton3="{DOWN}"
sysvariableCenterButton="^e"
sysvariableSleepInterval=100
sysvariableEnterKey="{ENTER}"
sysvariableLeftButton="^l"
sysvariableRightArrow="{RIGHT}"
sysvariableRightArrow2="{RIGHT 2}"
sysvariableEscapeKey="{ESC}"
sysvariableSelectAll="^a"
'
'### SYSTEM VARIABLES END (DO NOT EDIT) ###
'
'### USER FRIENDLY VARIABLES START ###
'
variableTitlename=InputBox("Enter Titlename for the Document")
variableTitleFont=InputBox("Enter a valid font for title. Case Sensitive")
variableFont=InputBox("Enter a valid font for the Document body. Case     Sensitive")
variableFontSize=InputBox("Enter a valid font size for the Document body:")
variableTitleSize=InputBox("Enter a valid font size for the title:")
variableTitleBolded=InputBox("Enter True or False as to whether the title is     bolded:")
variablePageNumberEnabled=InputBox("Enter True or False as to whether page     numbers are enabled:")
variableHeaderEnabled=InputBox("Enter True or False as to whether Page     Numbers are enabled:")
variableHeader1=InputBox("Enter first header title:")
variableHeader2=InputBox("Enter second header title:")
variableHeader3=InputBox("Enter third header title:")
variableHeaderFont=InputBox("Enter font for headers")
variableHeaderFontSize=InputBox("Enter header font sizes:")
variableNarrowMargins=InputBox("Enter True or False as to whether Narrow     Margins are enabled")
'
'### USER FRIENDLY VARIABLES END ###
'
'### NOTIFICATIONS START ###
'
objShell.Popup sysvariablePopupString, sysvariablePopupDuration,         sysvariablePopupTitle
'
'### NOTIFICATIONS END ###
'
'### MACRO START ###
'
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableCenterButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableFontButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys variableTitleFont
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableSizeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys variableTitleSize
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys variableTitlename
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
If variableTitleBolded="True" Then
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableBoldButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
Else
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
End If
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableLeftButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableFontButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys variableFont
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableSizeButton
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys variableFontSize
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
If variableHeaderEnabled="True" Then
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableInsertButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHeaderButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHeaderButton2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableRightArrow
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys variableHeader1
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableRightArrow2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys variableHeader2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableRightArrow2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys variableHeader3
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableSelectAll
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableFontButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys variableHeaderFont
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableHomeButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableSizeButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys variableHeaderFontSize
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEscapeKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
Else
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
End If
If variablePageNumberEnabled="True" Then
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableInsertButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariablePageButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariablePageButton2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariablePageButton3
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEscapeKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
Else
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
End If
If variableNarrowMargins="True" Then
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariablePageLayoutButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableMarginButton
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableMarginButton2
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
    wshShell.sendKeys sysvariableEnterKey
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
Else
    Wscript.Sleep sysvariableSleepInterval
End If
'
'### MACRO END ###
'
'### FINAL NOTIFICATIONS START ###
'
objShell.Popup sysvariableEndPopupString, sysvariablePopupDuration, sysvariableEndPopupTitle
```

Comment: Read about VBScript loop structures in [Statements (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw9cadb(v=vs.84).aspx): try   `For..Next` or `Do..Loop` or `While..Wend` or `For Each...Next`. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You can do this easily with a `For` loop and the `Execute` function.

Comment: What can be the commad 1 , command 2 and command 3 ? Please you should clarify your question in order to get the best solution faster !

Comment: @Hackoo What do you mean they have a command to run *(doesn't matter what it is called)* and want to pass 1 argument and they want to do this DRY. What's to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `For ... Next` statement loop to iterate through and then call the `Execute` function to run the commands.

Something like this

```
Dim index, count
'Number of commands to execute
count = 3
For index = 1 To count
  'Both steps performed for each iteration
  Execute "Command " & index
  WScript.Sleep 1000
Next
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Using the `Eval` and `Execute` Functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131103/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/030300-1.shtml)
- [VBScript Language Reference - Execute Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [VBScript Language Reference - For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3hh43e(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: How can I use this with my code? I'm new to VBS, and it's quite difficult for me to grasp the context. Could you substitute some of my code in as an example?

Comment: @ice To be honest [the latest example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32575472/3) is far more involved then [the initial example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32575472/2) that seemed a simple pattern to do recursively. It can still be done but would require using an `Array` to hold the instructions to process then call them using `Execute()`.

Comment: Ah, so I'll have to assign each sendkeys command to an array individually and then call using the Execute command? Do I execute each array with a counter like 'counter = counter + 1' and 'Execute Command(counter)'?